# Does mono application bundled with mkbundle use app.config?

Tags: mono, config, mkbundle

I build my application like this:

> ```
> mkbundle --static -o de --deps DeviceEmulator.exe 
> UnionArgParser.dll Emulators.dll NLog.dll Protocol.dll
> FSharpx.Core.dll
> ```

When i run ./de on same machine application works fine.
But when i copy to other machine (i use lxc container) and start i got an error:

> Exception: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: 
>      Error Initializing the configuration system.
>      System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section
>      (/home/ubuntu/tests/device/DeviceEmulator.exe.config line 3)

**Addition**

I found solution myself. Need to pass parameter `--machine-config <path to my mono/runtime/etc/mono/4.0/machine.config>` when bundle. This is solve problem with error.

Comment: Thanks for leaving the solution here. You should in fact post that as an answer.